# How to handle Whitelabel 404 error in Spring Boot without using Thymeleaf or other template engines

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot + Spring Security application with React JS for client. I want to have a custom styled 404 error page in it without using Thymeleaf.

My Spring Boot version is 2.0.0.M2

The war file structure is

```
root-dir
|- WEB-INF
|   |- lib
|   |- classes
|   |   |- static
|   |   |   |- * (react dist)
|   |   |- * (other files)
|- org
|- META-INF
```

My war file build process will be as follows.

1. Using Gradle npm plugin, build the ReactJS distribution
2. Gradle task that will copy the distribution to `static` directory in war
3. Build war finally

Please help me on this to solve.

Comment: You can disable the whitelabel page and create your own error page instead. Please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Comment: In the link, they have used Thymeleaf. Is it possible to do without any template engines usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to disable the white label page.
Just add a file named **404.html** under the **src/main/resources/public/error** directory.

Baeldung.com indicates **src/main/resources/public/errors**, which does not work, at least with SpringBoot 2.1.x. Use the singular **error** and you will be good.

All of this work without any template engine in the project's dependencies.

Comment: Great. It works. I have also added 401.html which is also found recently.